# Equations involving the inner product

Tags: analysis, inner-products

I've been reading chapter 2 of Ward Cheney's *Analysis for Applied Mathematics*, and he gives the following question:

> Find all solutions to the equation $\langle x,a \rangle c = b $, assuming that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are given vectors in an inner-product space.

This problem looks like it will require some case work. For instance, if $b=0$ then any $x\in \{a\}^\perp$ is a solution. Also, there can be no solution if $b\neq0$ and either $a$ or $c$ is zero. Further, if $b\neq0$ and $c$ is orthogonal to $b$, then there can be no solution since we would have

$$\langle b,b \rangle  = \langle \langle x,a \rangle c,b \rangle = 0,$$
which is a contradiction.

So then the most interesting case is when none of the three knowns is zero, and $\langle b,c \rangle \neq0$. However, I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=0$ then $b=0$ and $c$ is arbitrary.

If $c=0$ then $b=0$ and $x$ can be anything.

The LHS is a scalar times $c$.  So if $b$ is not a scalar times $c$ then there is no solution.

If $a\ne0$ and $c\ne0$ and $b$ is a scalar times $c$ then $b=\lambda c$, where $\lambda$ can be found since $b$ and $c$ are given.  So $\langle x,a\rangle=\lambda$.  Write $x=\alpha a+y$, where $y\perp a$; then we get
$$\alpha=\frac{\lambda}{\langle a,a\rangle}\ .$$
So the solution in this case is
$$x=\frac{\lambda}{\langle a,a\rangle}a+y$$
where $b=\lambda c$ and $y\perp a$.

Comment: Your solution makes sense. Thank you. This shows that the solution is unique up to adding something from $\{a\}^\perp$. Is there a geometric interpretation (say we're in finite dimensional space for the moment) for why the solution is a sum of something from the span of $a$ and something from the orthogonal complement? I want to eventually look at equations of the form $x + \langle x,a \rangle c=b$, so maybe that interpretation would be helpful.

Comment: If $a\ne0$ then every $x$ can be written uniquely as $\lambda a+y$ with $y\perp a$.  This gives$$\lambda  a+y+\lambda\langle a,a\rangle c=b\ .$$If $a,b,c$ are given you can also write $b,c$ in terms of $a$ and something perpendicular, and this should lead to a solution.

Comment: This seems to introduce too many unknowns. However, if we know $\langle b,a \rangle \neq 0$, and write $x=\lambda c + b$ , then we can solve for $\lambda$ to obtain $$ x=b-\frac{\langle b,a \rangle}{1+\langle c,a \rangle}c, $$ where the orthogonality relation ensures the factor in the second term is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $b \neq \alpha c$ for some scalar $\alpha$ (and $c \neq 0$), consider taking the inner product of both sides with $c - \frac{\langle b,c \rangle}{|\langle b,b \rangle|} b$. Note that this non-zero vector is orthogonal to $b$ but not to $c$.

Comment: I think you meant $c-\frac{\langle c,b \rangle}{\Vert b \Vert ^2 }b$ (I'm working over the complex numbers, so the direction matters here).  We also need $b\neq 0\neq a$. With that, we get 

$$ \langle x,a \rangle \left( \Vert c \Vert ^2 -\frac{\vert \langle b,c \rangle \vert ^2}{\Vert b \Vert ^2} \right)=0 $$

Since $b\neq0$, then $x\notin \{a\}^\perp$ and since $b$ and $c$ are linearly independent, the second factor cannot be zero. This implies there is no solution. So for nonzero $a,b,c$, a solution exists only if $b$ is in the span of $c$. Is that where your hint was going?